# Subquery returned more than 1 value/ call a scalar valued function with variable table parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to call a SQL function with parameter from a table variable, but when i call it i got the error

> Sub query returned more than 1 value

because table has multiple row. How can i call the function row by row from the table variable ?

This is my code:

```
    DECLARE @FromDate NVARCHAR(10) = '20150809',
    @ToDate NVARCHAR(10) = '20150815',
    @EmpID NVARCHAR(6)= '000752'

    DECLARE @AttendanceTable TABLE(date NVARCHAR(30),Funckey NVARCHAR(10))
    insert into @AttendanceTable(date,Funckey) SELECT date,Funckey from PERS_Attendance WHERE DATE between convert(date,@fromDate) AND CONVERT(Date,@toDate)

    select * FROM @AttendanceTable

select dbo.SM_GetScheduleIn(@EmpID,(select date from @AttendanceTable))
```

Comment: Added sql-server tag based on syntax used in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select dbo.SM_GetScheduleIn(@EmpID,(select date from @AttendanceTable))
```

should be

```
select dbo.SM_GetScheduleIn(@EmpID,date) from @AttendanceTable
```